# Can I enable my fingerprint lockscreen whitout (!) enabling encryption

Tags: lock-screens, encryption, bootloader-lock

I like to **regularly backup** my **data** partition using TWRP. I noticed once I enable my fingerprint **screenlock**, TWRP is unable to access my data partition because Android 8.0 encrypts it from the moment I set a **lockscreen password** (obligated when I enable fingerprint lockscreen). For the moment "**preserve force encryption**" is **off** in Magisk. Can I take the risk and enable my fingerprint screenlock now? Or will it encrypt my data partition again? I don't want to format my data again and reinstall everything. My **bootloader is unlocked** and my phone is a Samsung SM-G935E

Comment: It is probable your device is already encrypted, but without a screen unlock authentication set by you TRWP uses the default Android password, thus, making you believe setting screen lock authentication encrypts data. Verify first whether device is encrypted or not.

Comment: "preserve force encryption" is off and "settings -> security -> encrypt device" is available. anything else I can check?

Comment: Your device (S7 edge) should be encrypted by default. Therefore as Firelord it is more a question of the password used for encryption. Usually TWRP should be able to access your data if provided with the PIN/password. Therefore you should try to set a simple PIN. Afterwards TWRP should ask for it and you can again make a backup.

Comment: I remember I did a format of my data partition because my device was in a bootloop and I couldn't access the data partition with twrp. Is it possible that TWRP cannot decrypt or does not ask for a password on Samsung S7 edge devices? As it never did with me in previous installs. How can I check if my device is encrypted now? It is not in a default state and is running TheGalaxyProject with Magisk pre-installed.